# console.log not showing in Parse Logs page

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In the below cloud code i would like to get a feedback of the saveAll function but after calling the code from my client in the parse Logs page i can only see:

`I2014-10-08T15:28:32.930Z] v249: Ran cloud function acceptMeetingBis for user dyGu143Xho with:
Input: {"meetingId":"bUSTGNhOer"}
Result: Meeting accepted`

Here is my cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("acceptMeetingBis", function(request, response) {
var userAcceptingTheMeeting = request.user;
var meetingId = request.params.meetingId;
var changedObjects = [];
var queryForMeeting = new Parse.Query("MeetingObject");
queryForMeeting.equalTo("objectId", meetingId);
queryForMeeting.first({
    success: function(meeting) {
        var userCreatorOfMeeting = meeting.get("user");
        userAcceptingTheMeeting.increment("acceptedMeetings", +1);
        changedObjects.push(userAcceptingTheMeeting);
        meeting.add("participantsObjectId", userAcceptingTheMeeting.id);
        if (meeting.get("participantsObjectId").length === meeting.get("meetingNumberOfPersons")) {
            meeting.set("isAvailable", false);
        }
        changedObjects.push(meeting);
        Parse.Object.saveAll(changedObjects, {
            success: function(objects) {
                console.log("Successfully saved objects"); //this line doesn't show up
                response.success("objects saved");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                // An error occurred while saving one of the objects.
                response.error(error);
            }
        });
        //future query and push notifications will go here
        response.success("Meeting accepted");
    },
    error: function() {
        response.error("Failed to accept the meeting");
    }
});
});
```

I will also need to add some push and another nested query after the saveAll() but before doing/trying that i would like to know if this is the right method to use or if i have to build the code in a different way. I'm new to javascript and honestly i'm struggling to understand some concepts, like promises. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to

`Parse.Object.saveAll`

is asynchronous, and you call

`response.success("Meeting accepted")`

immediately after making the asynchronous call, which ends the cloud code running of the method. If you simply replace the

`response.success("objects saved")`

with

`response.success("Meeting accepted")`

you should get what you want.

---

I didn't see the rest of your question about promises. You should check out [Parse's documentation on chaining promises](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-chaining), which is what you want here.

Essentially, here's what you'll want to do:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("acceptMeetingBis", function(request, response) {
    var userAcceptingTheMeeting = request.user;
    var meetingId = request.params.meetingId;
    var changedObjects = [];
    var meetingToAccept;
    var queryForMeeting = new Parse.Query("MeetingObject");
    queryForMeeting.get(meetingId).then(function(meeting) {
        meetingToAccept = meeting;
        var userCreatorOfMeeting = meeting.get("user");
        userAcceptingTheMeeting.increment("acceptedMeetings", +1);
        return userAcceptingTheMeeting.save();
    }).then(function(userWhoAcceptedMeetingNowSaved) {
        meetingToAccept.add("participantsObjectId", userWhoAcceptedMeetingNowSaved.id);
        if (meetingToAccept.get("participantsObjectId").length === meetingToAccept.get("meetingNumberOfPersons")) {
            meetingToAccept.set("isAvailable", false);
        }
        return meetingToAccept.save();
    }).then(function(savedMeeting) {
        response.success("Meeting accepted");
    }, function(error) {
        response.error("Failed to accept the meeting");
    });
});
```

For each asynchronous action you want to do, perform it at the end of one of the `.then` functions and return the result (it returns a promise). Keep adding `.then` functions until you're done all the work you want to do, at which point call `response.success`.